# Save playwright-scrapy data in django models

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, playwright

I am new to playwright_scrapy. I want to save save scrapy yield data in django models.
Here is my pilpeline.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter
from .enums import ModelChoices
from tp_core.models import (
    ScrapPatent,
    Logo, 
    Patent, 
    Trademark, 
    Name, PatentThreat
    )

model = 'Patent'
class ScrapyappPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if model == ModelChoices.PATENT.value:
            quote = PatentThreat(patent_name=item.get('title'), description=item.get('description'),file= item.get('image'), URL = item.get('url'),contact_details=item.get('data'))
            quote.save()
            return item
        if model == ModelChoices.TRADEMARK.value:
            quote = Trademark(name=item.get('title'), description=item.get('description'),file= item.get('image'), url_trademark = item.get('url'))
            quote.save()
            return item
        if model == ModelChoices.LOGO.value:
            quote = Logo(title=item.get('title'), description=item.get('description'),logo_file= item.get('image'), url_logo = item.get('url'))
            quote.save()
            return item
        if model == ModelChoices.NAME.value:
            quote = Name(name=item.get('title'), description=item.get('description'),file= item.get('image'), url_name = item.get('url'))
            quote.save()
            return item
```

I added also these line to settings.py

```
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    
}

TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"
```

i also try with
`quote = Trademark(name=item.get('title'), description=item.get('description'),file= item.get('image'), url_trademark = item.get('url')) quote.save() return item`

Its running well but not saving value in django models, Please anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable your pipeline in the settings file.

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'yourproject.pipelines.ScrapyappPipeline': 800,
}
```

you can read more details [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#activating-an-item-pipeline-component)

Comment: Thanks , for replying. Yes, I already added this on my settings.py file but still I'm not getting value in django models